# Any way to format S3 notifications via SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am testing SNS notifications for new objects created in a bucket. When I receive SNS notification it looks like a bunch of code with parameters. Something like:

```
{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"2.0","eventSource":"aws:s3","awsRegion":"eu-west-1","eventTime":"2016-08-28T09:12:36.709Z","eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put","userIdentity":.......
```

I want to convert this data into a human-readable format, something like:

```
Time: xxxxxxx
Bucket: xxxxxxxx 
Event: xxxxx
```

Is there any way to do it? Some walkthrough that I should know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all the changes this is the final code:

```
var util = require('util');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));

    var s3Event = event.Records[0];

    var srcBucket = s3Event.s3.bucket.name;
    var srcEvent = s3Event.eventName;
    var time = s3Event.eventTime;
    var nombre = s3Event.s3.object.key;
    var tamano = s3Event.s3.object.size;

    var msg = "Nuevo objeto \r\n" +
              "Hora: " + time + "\r\n" +
              "Bucket: " + srcBucket + "\r\n" + 
              "Evento: " + srcEvent + "\r\n" +
              "Objeto: " + nombre + "\r\n" +
              "Tamaño (en MB): " + tamano/1048576 + "\r\n";

    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    sns.publish({
        Message: msg,
        TopicArn: 'TOPIC_ARN'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(msg);
        context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');  
    });

}
```

Note that I have added 2 new variables: "nombre" that gets the name of the file created and "tamano" that gets the size. That last one is given in bytes so I convert it to megabytes with a simple operation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming your SNS notification subscribers are email endpoints?

I believe the simplest way to do this would be to use AWS Lambda to do the formatting.

Instead of publishing s3 events to SNS, publish them to an AWS Lambda function. In the Lambda function, write some code to format the event records as you want them. Then the Lambda function can publish a message to the SNS topic.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html for a tutorial related to setting up a Lambda function to generate a thumbnail whenever an image is uploaded to S3.

It demonstrates how, in the lambda function, you can access the event properties.

Taking from that example and adjusting based on your situation:

```
var util = require('util');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');  
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';


exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));

    var s3Event = event.Records[0];

    var srcBucket = s3Event.s3.bucket.name;
    var srcEvent = s3Event.eventName;
    var time = s3Event.eventTime;

    var msg = "Time: " + time + "\r\n" +
              "Bucket: " + srcBucket + "\r\n" + 
              "Event: " + srcEvent + "\r\n";

    var sns = new AWS.SNS();

    sns.publish({
        Message: msg,
        TopicArn: 'TOPIC_ARN'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        }
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(data);
        context.done(null, 'Function Finished!');  
    });

}
```

(The above also includes a snippet from https://gist.github.com/jeremypruitt/ab70d78b815eae84e037 regarding publishing to sns.)

This is just an untested example - I recommend following the tutorial above, as it also talks you through the various permissions and other configurations you need to make - but the above function should serve as a starting point.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Any clues about the code that I should use? I'm not really much into this kind of structure.

Comment: Edited to suggest going directly from s3 to lambda, so you don't need two SNS topics after all, and included some sample code.

Comment: Although it seems to be correct, I haven't been able to make it work. I am getting an error that says "util" is not defined.

Comment: Sorry about that - you need `var util = require('util');` at the top.  It's in the original in the AWS tutorial, but I missed it in the sample code - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html.  It's only used for dumping the event to the log in the first line of the function, so you can remove both lines if you don't need that.

Comment: Now I am getting notifications with plain text, like if the variable contents weren't loading: Time: + ${time}. I have tried messing with the code but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Can I check if your Lamda function is using Node.js 4.3 as the runtime? If not, it may not process the string interpolation (the "${time}" part) properly.  Either way, I've updated the answer with a small change to the `var msg = ...` part that should make it work either way.  If not, can you link to a copy of the log message dumped by the `Reading options from event` line?

Comment: Now it is working. I think that the error was that we were passing the variables as plain text. This is the  final code (there vas a little error on your change):   
var msg = "Time: " + time + "\r\n" +
              "Bucket: " + srcBucket + "\r\n" + 
              "Event: " + srcEvent + "\r\n";